# Where to store credentials for VSIX - Visual Studio 2017 Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, store, credentials, vsix

**Context:**
I'm writing VSIX Extension for Visual Studio 2017 which needs connection to REST API that requires user authentication.
I decide to use VSPackage to provide service for my extension.

To be able to connect and authenticate users I would like to store somewhere user credentials, it could be either username and password or OAuth token - doesn't matter.

**Question:**
**What will be the best place to store credentials information for VSIX?**

Requirements:

- Credentials should not be stored as plain text
- Should not be stored in text file
- Should be stored per user
  (We can have more then one windows user, One Windows User = One VS User)
- Should be available in all running instances of Visual Studio
- Should work with VS2017 (15.0+) Community, Pro and Enterprise

As for now I've take a look at [***WritableSettingsStore***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn949254.aspx) in ***UserSettings*** scope in VS but it was stored in registry by plain text and I would not want to implement my own security on top of that

I've tried also to find more information about [***IVsCredentialStorageService***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.connected.credentialstorage.ivscredentialstorageservice?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) but it is poorly documented and lack of information about how to use it properly and if it is per user or per system.

Comment: I belive IVsCredentialStoreService goes to registry's HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio (even VS 2017, but I'm not sure)

Comment: VS indeed stores values for IVsCredentialStoreService in TokenStorage registry. It looks that VS2017 also use 14.0 registry key. 
After some research in registry and try use IVsCredentialStoreService I found also that VS store their VS User info and session tokens.
Still is is undocumented but probably this is the right way to go

I just wonder is everyone can read this? For example VSIX can use credential stored by another Extension or IDE itself? 
I would rather avoid that.

Comment: Undercover, it uses the ProtectedData class, so yes, of course, the user can read all settings stored here. There's no way around this apart from using your own key, your own system. Even in this case, It just depend on the level of protection you are seeking. This is not related to VSIX or Visual Studio or even Windows. The question would become "how to store credential securely on a machine"? Theoratically, you can't. If I can run, I can hack it.

Comment: @SimonMourier and Damian Kras I'm sorry to come here and ask for help but I would be really grateful if you could share your knowledge about that. [I couldn't figure out how to access the tokens used by Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205238/get-nuget-credentials-stored-somewhere-by-visual-studio-in-a-vsix-project). Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows Credentials Store, allows you to store in a secure manner per user: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CredentialManagement/

Comment: It is some kind of solution but requires additional package embaded into VSIX, and in case we have strongly named assembly we need to sign 3rd party assembly. (strongly named assembly is default configuration for VSIX with VSPackage)  
  
Also this is not the best way to go if you wouldn't like expose credential to other programs in Windows System. This package is not maintained and code is unavailable.

Comment: Source code is available in the zip download from Codeplex !?